# Can I clean install Windows 8 after free upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded to Windows 10 from my Windows 8.1 (Windows 8 originally). My 30 days in which I could roll-back are over, but I want to comeback to Windows 8 since Windows 10 is causing problems.

I can download an ISO of Windows 8 using media creation tool, then burn it onto a DVD/CD. My Windows 8 key is an OEM version so the product key is tied to the motherboard.

Can I install Windows 8 and it will activate? Or did the product key get consumed by Windows 10 and I have to stay with it?

Comment: The 30 days just refers to when the previous installation will get deleted if you do an upgrade, so this should have no effect on the activation possibility. Theoretically Microsoft could do something from their server-side but I have yet to hear that they do. You might have to simply try and see (maybe on a separate partition). Please report back, I would be interested in this as well (but one has to keep in mind that Microsoft might do changes to their servers at any time).

Comment: "So I want to know can I install Windows 8 and it will activate?" - Since the answer to this question is literally, a one word answer, I will just leave a comment.  Yes;  You can install Windows 8.1 on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I wil try installing Windows 8 on a different partition just incase. I will use the multios feature. I will report what I will find. Thanks for the reply, both phk and Ramhound.